# what exactly is scalerotationpart of a matrix3? [maxscript]

Tags: maxscript

Matrix3 in maxscript implements a 4x4 transformation matrix.

http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_D77C780A_4E8A_4528_949F_CC09AAE048DA_htm

it allows to access rotation, scale and translation directly through subproperties. However, there is also a "scalerotationpart", which is a quaternion:

```
<matrix3>.rotationpart: Quat, read-only
<matrix3>.translationpart: Point3, read-only
<matrix3>.scalerotationpart: Quat, read-only
<matrix3>.scalepart: Point3, read-only
```

rotationpart as quaternion makes sense. translationpart as Point3 makes sense. scalepart as Point3 makes sense. But what is scalerotationpart? Intuitively, I would expect this to be  the 3x3 submatrix that encodes both rotation and scale - however, it's returned as a Quaternion and as far as I know a quaternion cannot encode both rotation and scale together.

What exactly is this?

Comment: Maybe it is just the unit quaternion scaled by some value ... i.e. a non-unit quaternion.  Can you look at one of these to see what the quaternion magnitude is?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, as matrix3 is homogeneous matrix, this quaternion is used to store coordinate system of the object? it's "grid" - it would be point3 to describe normal vector + value to describe "grid scale" of the object